# OpenJDK and Cacao on ARM: Unknown trap instruction

Tags: arm, ubuntu-10.04, java

I'm trying to launch a java application on an ARM platform running Ubuntu 10.04. When using the plain `java` command it runs fine. When trying to use cacao vm `java -cacao` then I get the following error:

```
LOG: [0x2aac4540] trap_handle: Unknown trap instruction at 0x2efa793c
LOG: [0x2aac4540] PC=0x2efa793c
LOG: [0x2aac4540] Aborting...
LOG: [0x2aac4540] Backtrace (4 stack frames):
LOG: [0x2aac4540] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/arm/cacao/libjvm.so(+0x36244) [0x2ac58244]
LOG: [0x2aac4540] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/arm/cacao/libjvm.so(+0x363da) [0x2ac583da]
LOG: [0x2aac4540] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/arm/cacao/libjvm.so(+0x3e11e) [0x2ac6011e]
LOG: [0x2aac4540] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/arm/cacao/libjvm.so(+0x47248) [0x2ac69248]
```

The java version i use:

```
$ java -cacao -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
IcedTea Runtime Environment (1.8.13) (6b18-1.8.13-0ubuntu1~10.04.1)
CACAO (build 1.1.0pre2, compiled mode)
```

- Is there something wrong with my application?
- Is there a way to tell which instruction actually causes the error?
- Do I miss something else what is needed to use caco vm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to CACAO developers this CACAO version as well as the IcedTea version are completely outdated. It seems that Ubuntu 10.04 OpenJDK on arm is not actively maintained.

To get CACAO VM working a compilation from source is needed. There is a little how-to in the CACAO wiki on [how to build CACAO with IcedTea](http://c1.complang.tuwien.ac.at/cacaowiki/IcedTea).